# Canonical quantization of gauge field under the Schwarzschild background

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime, quantization

I have read some papers (e.g.[0803.2001](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2001.pdf), [PhysRevD.24.297](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.24.297), especially section 4 in [1809.03467](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03467.pdf) ) to find the mode expansion of gauge field under the Schwarzschild background.
In paper [PhysRevD.24.297](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.24.297), the authors follow the treatment on the Rindler horizon ([0803.2001](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2001.pdf)) to find a mode expansion on the Schwarzschild horizon.

But

- The paper find a coordinate $(t,\xi,y,\phi)$ to decompose the metric near the horizon region as $\text{ Rindler}\times S^2$. But to treat the quantum effect measured by a physical observer at a point of null-infinity, a more reasonable choice is $(u,v,x^A)$.
- They perform a mode expansion of the Maxwell field as eqs (4.34),(A.5). That is very unlike the result in flat spacetime QFT
  $$A_{\mu}\sim \epsilon^{\alpha}_{\mu}e^{ipx}a_{\alpha}(p)\, .$$
  Or, say, the absence of polarization vector in the mode expansion.

**Thus my problem is**

Can we find a mode expansion of the gauge field like
$$A_\mu\sim \epsilon^\alpha_\mu V(\omega,\mathbf{p}) a_{\alpha}(p)$$
under the Schwarzschild background by using $(u,v,x^A)$ frame?